# How can I condition an Azure Pipelines stage on the value of a UI variable?

Tags: azure-pipelines

My pipeline has stages defined by templates. I would like to run these stages only if the value of a UI variable (set in the Variables tab) is true. I can not use a YAML variable, as I need to regularly and quickly toggle this variable without having to go through deploying changes to the YAML file. I understand that I can not use the condition parameter under the template field, so I have been trying to use expressions. However, I can not seem to reference my UI variable in an expression. My closest attempt has been something like:

```
variables:
  ENABLE_STAGE: $(enableStage)

stages:
- ${{ if eq(variables.ENABLE_STAGE, true) }}:
  - template: template.yml
```

where enableStage is the UI variable. variables.ENABLE_STAGE just ends up evaluating to the literal string '$(enableStage)'. Is what I'm trying to do supported? If not, how can I easily enable/disable template stages from the UI.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my test, the variable from the UI is not supported.

You could use the parameters to set true or false to enable/disable template stages from the UI.

YAML like:

```
parameters:
- name: enableStage # name of the parameter; required
  type: boolean # data type of the parameter; required
  default: false


stages:
- ${{ if eq(parameters.enableStage, false) }}:
  - template: template.yml
```

[image]

For more information, you could refer to:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#variables

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is there a way to set a parameter value from UI for an indefinite amount of time? My pipeline runs hourly, so I need a way to easily disable the stage until an undetermined time. This solution seems to only allow me to disable/enable the stage for a single given run.

Comment: For reference, this pipeline was adapted from a classic pipeline, where it was simple in the UI to detach one stage from the next as needed

Comment: This is exceptionally frustrating that if conditions can't reference variables set in the UI. I'm trying to achieve the same thing and it's practically impossible. Anything in roadmap to support vars set in the UI?

Comment: What I did in the end is split the files
- azure-pipelines-function.yaml 
- azure-pipelines-api.yaml

both of these then call azure-pipelines.yml, this contains the steps needed to build both api and functions. When api yaml executes it feeds a param called "ProjectToBuild' with value api, this can then be used in "if" conditions and using UI it's possible to change the values although in my case it's no needed as the function yaml does it for me - this is what I initially wanted to control via UI vars.